# How can you time requests with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

I'm familiar with using a HttpModule to time requests but those don't really hook into ASP.NET MVC's view system. Can this be done by starting a timer somewhere in global.asax and then accessing it in _layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can check the start time and end time of a request in Begin_Request and End_Request events of application class
2) You can define a custom HttpModule
3)You can define a custom attribute as follows:

```
public class RequestTimerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Mark the Start Time 
                MarkTime("Start");
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Mark the Start Time 
                MarkTime("End");
    }

    void MarkTime(string EventName)
    {
        //Handle the logic here to log the time 
    }        
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach - didn't know about this attribute. Can you inject HTML (ie the execution time) into the current response from the OnResultsExecuted override?

Comment: The cleanest way to do that would be to add it to ViewData in OnResultExecuting so it can be rendered by the view. Obviously that won't include the view rendering time, but anything potentially time consuming should be in the controller anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I use the controller's `Initialize` method to set a flag in [`HttpContext.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx):

```
HttpContext.Items["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Then print it in your view, or wherever:

```
<%
// We only set this in DEBUG builds
var startTime = HttpContext.Current.Items["StartTime"] as DateTime?
if(startTime.HasValue)
{ %>
    <%=(DateTime.Now - startTime.Value).TotalSeconds.ToString("0.00000")%> seconds
<%
}
%>
```